# Installing newest Python on openSUSE

Tags: python, python-3.3, opensuse, suse

I installed Python on an openSUSE system (see version below) using the Zypper package manager. This gives me Python 3.2, but some packages require Python 3.3. Updating with `zypper update python3` stays on Python 3.2. How can I upgrade to 3.3, ideally using the package manager and reusing the rest of my working Python installation (site packages, pip...)?

```
openSUSE 12.2 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12.2
CODENAME = Mantis
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the [devel:languages:python:Factory](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/devel%3alanguages%3apython%3aFactory) repository or use the *1 Click Install* and a Python 3.3.2 version form [here](http://software.opensuse.org/package/python3) (e.g. from the above repo).
(Show other versions->openSUSE 12.2->Show unstable packages->1 Click Install)

To use it with *zypper* only (no GUI) you can add the repo as follows:

```
sudo zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python:/Factory/openSUSE_12.2/devel:languages:python:Factory.repo
```

Then, to use packages from that repo you should give the repo a higher priority (in this case higher priority means lower number 0=high, 100=low). To know the repo id use `zypper lr` and search for the repo number in the output. Then use the following command to change the priority:

```
 sudo zypper mr -p priority repo_number
```

You could use e.g. 50 as priority if your other repos have the standard priority of 99.
Then use `zypper update python3` to update python.

Comment: What would be the `zypper addrepo ...` command for adding the repository?

Comment: I should mention that I have only ssh access to the machine, no GUI.

Comment: Added the command to the answer (I mostly don't use zypper, but I have tried the above, so I'm quiet sure it is correct :).

Comment: I have added the repository, but what is the next step? `zypper update python3` says the package is up to date (= 3.2).

Comment: You probably need to change the priority of the repo. I'll add the code to the answer.

Comment: Probably `zypper update python3` will say (in my case) `zypper install python3-3.3.2-76.1.x86_64` then use that.

Comment: This worked, but note that all previously installed python packages will be uninstalled or broken.

Comment: Oh. I don't know actually why that happens (why they don't have simply python 3.x as dependency), but you could try to add this `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python3/openSUSE_12.2/devel:languages:python3.repo` repo and see if it works.

Comment: As time passes, the versions change. For OpenSuse 15.2 run `zypper addrepo --repo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python:/Factory/openSUSE_Leap_15.2/devel:languages:python:Factory.repo`. This will enable installing Python versions 3.8 and 3.9, but doing so will break stuff depending on factory-packaged Python 3.6.

Comment: More time has passed. I'm trying to update Python from 3.4.10 to whatever 3.6 patch (or later) is available on a SLES 12 SP5 system. The main factory now shown is <http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python:/Factory/15.4/>. Where are relevant repositories for SLES 12?

Answer (score 5):

You can follow the instructions below using pyenv:

```
# Step 1. Install pyenv

git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc

# Step 2. Install missing headers for all the Python modules to be built

sudo zypper install readline-devel sqlite3-devel libbz2-devel

# Step 3. Install the desired Python version

pyenv install 3.6.3
```

quoting from https://gist.github.com/antivanov/01ed4eac2d7486a170be598b5a0a4ac7