# Easy_install https unknown url error in python 3.3

Tags: python, linux, ssl, python-3.x

I'm installing python 3.3 on Suse Linux EC2 instance on amazon. The instance has already python 2.6 installed, so after installation of python 3.3 I work on virtual environment.

When I run `easy_install-3.3` in the virtual environment, I get the following error:

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
```

Note that: `easy_install` is working fine without the virtual env., so on Python 2.6 it's OK.

After making some search, I found posts advising that ssl might not be installed properly. So from python shell when I run:
import SSL

I get:

```
import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
   import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

According to the posts, I tried to edit Modules/Setup.dist before building Python 3.3 to `include _ssl.c` in the build as recommended in: 
[ImportError: No module named _ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128845/importerror-no-module-named-ssl)

Now, after make clean & make & make install of Python 3.3 I get errors for ssl and crypto libraries linking:

```
cannot find -lssl
cannot find -lcrypto
```

I assume it comes from this line in Setup.dist:

```
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

One last info: `openssl_cents` is already installed on suse linux

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: How did you install Python 3 in the first place? Have you tried [using the prebuilt version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875165/installing-newest-python-on-opensuse) instead of compiling it yourself?

Comment: I followed the next steps to build python: 1) wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tgz 2) tar xvfz Python-3.3.0.tgz 3) cd Python-3.3.0
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3 4) make  5) sudo make install

Comment: @Phillip how do you recommend to use prebuilt version? Note: I'm working on Suse linux. Thanks

Comment: You should try the prebuilt version then. "using the prebuilt version" in my above comment is a link to another question concerned with how to install it in Suse.