# Install Python 3.10.5 using pyenv

Tags: python, pyenv, virtual-environment, python-3.10

I want to install Python 3.10.5 (or at least Python >= 3.7.). I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48445296/7227146):

```
# Step 1. Install pyenv

git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc

# Step 2. Install missing headers for all the Python modules to be built

sudo zypper install readline-devel sqlite3-devel libbz2-devel

# Step 3. Install the desired Python version

pyenv install 3.10.5
```

until I got to `pyenv install 3.10.5`:

```
bscuser@localhost:~> pyenv install 3.10.5
/home/bscuser/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/share/python-build/3.7.13: line 1: prefer_openssl11: command not found

BUILD FAILED (openSUSE 15.3 using python-build 20180424)
```

I feel like it should be related to [this file](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/plugins/python-build/share/python-build/3.10.5).

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try restarting the shell? There are exports made to your bashrc file.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can. Use `pyenv update` first then running `pyenv install -list` you should be able to see versions `3.10.4`, `3.10.5`, `3.10.6`, `3.11.0`, even `3.11.1` now

Comment: In order to run `pyenv update`, you first need to install this plugin:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-update

After that, you should 3.10.5 when you run `pyenv install --list`

Answer (score 9):

here is similar case:

OS: `macOS`, previously installed old version `pyenv 1.2.26`

-> `pyenv install -l` see the latest python version is `3.10-dev`, not expected `3.10.x`

so need upgrade pyenv to latest version, here `pyenv 2.3.3`:

- on macOS: `brew upgrade pyenv`

  - you can refer [official doc](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv) to install/upgrade to latest pyenv

then can list to latest `python 3.10.5+`:

```
> pyenv install --list | grep 3.10
...
  3.10.0
  3.10-dev
  3.10.1
  3.10.2
  3.10.3
  3.10.4
  3.10.5
  3.10.6
  mambaforge-4.10.3-10
  miniconda-3.10.1
...
```

then can use pyenv install 3.10.6 normally:

`pyenv install 3.10.6`

so, here key point is:

- upgrade pyenv to latest version (here `pyenv 2.3.3`), then `pyenv install --list` can list/see latest python and install it `pyenv install 3.10.6`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.
Running `pyenv install -list` will give you a list of all possible python versions that can be installed, and it will only go as far as `3.10.4` as of this writing.

Comment: Nah, @Swakeert Jain really helped me, now I've got Python 3.10.5 on my computer: `bscuser@localhost:/run/media/bscuser/6C19-3138/Thesis/Corpus/Softcatala> python3
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun 15 2022, 10:33:16) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> `

Comment: @zest16 how did u manage? with `pyenv install -list` I can only see up until 3.10.4

Comment: I restarted the shell as @Swakeert Jain suggested.