# Installing newer Python on SLES 12

Tags: python, python-3.x, sles

I'm trying to update Python from 3.4.10 to whatever 3.6.x version is available for a SLES 12 SP5 system. 3.6 is no longer supported but sufficient for our needs; something newer is fine if it works on this OS. Suggestions greatly appreciated!

Where are relevant `zypper` repositories for SLES 12? The main factory now shown is http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python:/Factory/15.4/ but that seems too new.

Is some option available other than using a newer repository with `zypper`? (I only have SSH access to the machine. And, I'd prefer to avoid building Python from source if possible.)

[Installing newest Python on openSUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875165/installing-newest-python-on-opensus) seems related but doesn't answer my question because the repositories have changed or been removed.

---

I attempted to use the commands shown in [Installing newest Python on openSUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875165/installing-newest-python-on-opensus) but hit problems because the named repository no longer exists.

I then hunted around and found http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python:/Factory/15.4/

Stopped there because that repository doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 1):

SLE12-SP5 includes a package named `python36`, which contains version `3.6.8`. It was later updated to version `3.6.15`. See the output of `zypper search --details --type package python36`.